# Python scrapy+selenium scraper docker build error (error code 100)

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to deploy a python scraper to docker which requires selenium geckodriver and firefox.
I'm encountering a docker error 100 while trying to build a docker image.
Here's the docker code

```
FROM scrapinghub/scrapinghub-stack-scrapy:1.3-py3
#RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https unzip
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

#============================================
# Firefox and Geckodriver
#============================================
RUN apt-get update                             \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl firefox-esr \
&& rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*                \
&& curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local/bin \
&& apt-get purge -y ca-certificates curl

ENV TERM xterm
ENV SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE <my_project_name>.settings
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN python setup.py install
```

Here's the log that eventually comes up on my terminal

```
Error The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update                              && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl firefox-esr  && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
&& curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local/bin  && apt-get purge -y ca-certificates curl' 
returned a non-zero code: 100: 
{'code': 100, 'message': "The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update                              && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl firefox-esr  && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
&& curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local/bin  
&& apt-get purge -y ca-certificates curl' returned a non-zero code: 100"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when running `docker build .` directly it gave me the following log line pointing to the issue:

`#9 23.59 W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717`

If I remove the line:
`RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then it appears to be behave.